# How to browse and parse a pattern in a big and constantly growing log file?

Tags: python, parsing, data-manipulation

I am trying to browse a log file, but this log file is constantly growing. I don't want to read it from the start every time. There is a way to do that with python, but...

```
import re

def cogeUltimPosLogFile():
    with open('/tmp/lastPositionLogFile', 'r') as lf:
        content = lf.read()
    return int(content)

def marcaUltimPosLogFile(lpos):
    with open('/tmp/lastPositionLogFile', 'w') as lf:
        lf.write(str(lpos))

def log_browser(patron2agarar):
    lmatch=[]
    ln=0
    nbChar=0
    with open("camucamu.log", 'r') as contenilog:
        previousEndOfFile=cogeUltimPosLogFile()
        contenilog.seek(previousEndOfFile)
        for linea in contenilog:
            m = re.search(r"{}".format(patron2agarar), linea)
            if m:
                lmatch.append([ln, m.group(1)])
            nbChar=nbChar+len(linea)
            ln=ln+1
        setLastPositionLogFile(previousEndOfFile+nbChar)
    return lmatch
print(log_parser("(.*error.*)"))
```

But what if the file which have got the offset is re-initialized, or the python script runs for the first time?

Comment: Firstly I would recommend to write your code only in english, it will be understood by more people (mixing two languages is even more confusing). Regarding the script running for the first time you could check if  `/tmp/lastPositionLogFile` exists, if it doesn't exist you can assume it's the first execution. In the case that the file is reinitialised, you could save the last line together with the last end of file. Then you can check if the last line is the one you expect, if it isn't you can assume that the file was reinitialised.

Comment: What do you want to happen in those cases?

Comment: @PacoH. !! I speak more spanish than english. That's why I put them variable in my heart's language !!! Is that possible to work without a file (I mean put in in a memory buffer or something like this) ??

Comment: I don't understand, you are already using files to store the last position, why would you save the last line in a different manner.

Comment: @PacoH. because I will deploy this on several server with `chef`. Deploy another file will be a little creep :)

Comment: You don't have to deploy the `/tmp/lastPositionLogFile` file. The script can create it if it doesn't exist. Btw, by saving `lastPositionLogFile` in the `/tmp/` directory, you are going to lose the file basically each time the system boots.